# Formulating a dynamic class in Python

Tags: class, python-3.x

I've written a small function to formulate classes dynamically (or more specifically C-like structs, well, more or less) in Python that utilize **slots**. I was wondering if I did everything right. The classes can be instantiated, but I'm suspecting the **slots** are not being used correctly. Rather I have no idea if they indeed are used correctly.

```
def formulate(name, **data):
   def __init__(self, **data):
      self.__dict__.update(data)
   struct = type(name, (), data)
   struct.__init__ = __init__
   struct.__slots__ = data.keys()
   return struct
```

Thank you.
Alisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the `__slots__` and `__init__` as keys in the dict 
passed to `type`:

```
def formulate(name, **data):
   def __init__(self):                 # 1
       for key, val in data.items():   
           setattr(self, key, val)     # 2
   struct = type(name, (), {'__slots__': tuple(data.keys()), '__init__': __init__})
   return struct

Bar = formulate('Bar', **dict(a=1, b=2))  # 3
bar = Bar()                               # 4
print('__dict__' in dir(bar))
# False
print('__slots__' in dir(bar))
# True
print(bar.__slots__)
# ['a', 'b']
print(bar.a)
# 1
```

1. Note that I change the definition of `__init__` from

   ```
   def __init__(self, **data):
   ```

   to

   ```
   def __init__(self):
   ```

   If you use the original version, then the `data` used to update the
   slot keys must be provided by the call to `Bar`:

   ```
   bar = Bar(**dict(a=1, b=2))
   ```

   That would be bad since it would require you to repeat the same dict
   twice -- once at #4 and also at #3.

   It seems more likely that you want #3 to control the initial values
   of the slot keys. In that case, do not list `data` as an argument to
   `__init__`. By omitting it, Python uses the [LEGB rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) to look
   up the value of `data`. It would find it in the enclosed scope of
   the `formulate` function. `__init__` is then said to be [a closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29#Example).
2. Since a class with `__slots__` does not have a `__dict__` attribute
   by default, we can't/shouldn't use `self.__dict__.update(data)`.
   Instead, set the slot keys with `setattr`.

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks for the comments. I noticed if I left `__slots__` equal to `data.keys()`, then `bar.__slots__` ends up being `dict_keys(['b','a'])`. I don't know exactly how much space this requires, but I assumed it would require more space than `('a','b')`. Since the purpose of using `__slots__` is to save space, I thought `('a','b')` would be better. Is my thinking incorrect? Though maybe it really doesn't matter much since `__slots__` is attached to the class, not the instance?

Comment: @erkysun: Please feel free to improve if you see it is still lacking something.

Comment: Thank you, now I see where I went wrong. There's so much I still need to learn about Python. I'd like to add one thing though, I'd like to use the constructor, is there an alternative to your and mine versions of #1 that doesn't waste cycles, but still allows for the use of constructors?

Comment: Um, I'm confused? Where are the wasted cycles?

Comment: You said it yourself that data had to be walked twice in my (wrong) example. Let me reevaluate myself though. I might've misunderstood you.

Comment: It's okay, I misunderstood you. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: Oh good. I wasn't worried about wasted compute cycles as much as the annoyance of having to repeat oneself.

Comment: Hmm, I might've misunderstood myself too by uncommenting my version instead of yours. Cannot use the constructors... which is only natural since __init__ only takes self.

Comment: You can define `def __init__(self, **kwargs)`. Just don't call the `kwargs` parameter `data`, **if** you wish to access the `data` passed to `formulate`.